# select top values from union of two tables

Tags: sql, sql-server, union

trying to select the top 5 countries out of a union but it doesnt seem to be working.
this is my code:

```
SELECT TOP 5 country_number, country_name 
FROM
(
    SELECT country_number, country_name, COUNT(DISTINCT number)
    FROM
    (
        SELECT tc.country_number, tc.country_name, tdc.number, count(*) as tot_cnt
        FROM tblCountry tc
        INNER JOIN tblDivingClub AS tdc   ON tdc.country = tc.country_number
        INNER JOIN tblWorks_for  AS tw    ON tw.club_number = tdc.number
        INNER JOIN tblDiver      AS td    ON td.diver_number = tw.diver_number
        WHERE tw.end_working_date IS NULL
        GROUP BY tc.country_number, tc.country_name, tdc.number
        HAVING count(*) > 1
    ) as der
    GROUP BY country_number, country_name

    UNION 

    SELECT country_number, country_name, COUNT(DISTINCT number)
    FROM
    (
        SELECT tc.country_number, tc.country_name, tdc.number, count(*) as diveCount
        FROM tblCountry tc
        INNER JOIN tblDivingClub AS tdc   ON tdc.country = tc.country_number
        INNER JOIN tblDiving  AS tdv    ON tdv.diving_club = tdc.number
        WHERE tdv.date_of_diving >= DATEADD(year,-1, GETDATE())
        GROUP BY tc.country_number, tc.country_name, tdc.number
        HAVING count(*) > 6
    ) as der2
    GROUP BY country_number, country_name
)as combinedTable
```

it wont accept "combinedTable" or any other name / command  i place after "as".

Answer (score 1):

On your first query of the union you need a alias for the aggregate count.  All columns must have a name in the first query of a union.  Since you are using a function to calculate a value you must use an alias to assign it a name:

```
SELECT country_number, country_name, COUNT(DISTINCT number) as countNumber
```

Don't you love that the structure of SQL lends it to suggest the problem with your code is on the complete opposite end of the code file? :)

Comment: I wonder if the counterintuitive error has anything to do with assigning column aliases after the table alias? Because I believe you can theoretically do this: `... ) as combinedTable (country_number, country_name, number_count)`

Answer (score 1):

You can try specify a column name for

```
COUNT(DISTINCT number)
```

or even removing this column from both selects.

Answer (score 0):

You may be able to simplify your query, untested:

```
SELECT TOP 5 country_number, country_name
FROM
(
    SELECT tc.country_number, tc.country_name, tdc.number, count(*) as tot_cnt
    FROM tblCountry tc
    JOIN tblDivingClub AS tdc   ON tdc.country = tc.country_number
    JOIN tblWorks_for  AS tw    ON tw.club_number = tdc.number
    JOIN tblDiver      AS td    ON td.diver_number = tw.diver_number
    WHERE tw.end_working_date IS NULL
       OR tdv.date_of_diving >= DATEADD(year,-1, GETDATE())
    GROUP BY tc.country_number, tc.country_name, tdc.number
    HAVING count(*) > CASE WHEN tw.end_working_date IS NULL THEN 1 ELSE 6 END
) as T
```